# Replacing T2OLE with a ATL 7.0 String conversion classes and Macros

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl, ole

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/805c56f8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), using T2OLE in a loop may lead to stack overflow, my application uses T2OLE lot of places in the code inside loop for string conversion. I found that using [ATL 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) string conversion classes and macros has lot of benefits and it solves the stack overflow issue as well,

I tried using the ATL 7.0 as below,

```
_bstr_T example("Hello world");
for(i=o; i<10000; i++)
{
 Callsomemethod(i,T2OLE(example)); //This is where I need to replace T2OLE
}
void Callsomemethod(int k, cstring y)
{
....
}
```

I found that CT2OLE in ATL 7.0 is equivalent to T2OLE but when I replaced T2OLE with CT2OLE I am getting this issue

```
Error: No suitable user defined conversion from "ATL:CA2W" to Cstring exists
```

In the same way I have an other place where it does cstring to _bstr_t and when i replace over there I am getting this

```
 Error: No suitable user defined conversion from "ATL:CA2W" to _bstr_t exists
```

Can any one help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_bstr_t example("Hello world");
void Callsomemethod(CString y);
Callsomemethod(T2OLE(example)); //This is where I need to replace T2OLE
```

CString assumes you are passing `TCHAR*` compatible argument, whereas `x2OLE` macro gives you `WCHAR*` - you are using opposite direction conversion macro. And there might be missing conversion between `CString` and helper `CA2W` classes, where you need to help by providing a cast.

```
_bstr_t example("Hello world");
void Callsomemethod(CString y);
//void Callsomemethod(LPCTSTR y);

Callsomemethod(CString(example));
Callsomemethod(CString((BSTR) example));
Callsomemethod(OLE2CT(example));
Callsomemethod((LPCTSTR) OLE2CT(example));
```